# How can I find out why an object can't be JSON serialized?

Tags: python, json, django, django-rest-framework

I have a *very* simple use case of data that I wish to serialize to JSON, but I keep getting tripped by error `TypeError: <api.tests.MemberInfo object at 0x02B26210> is not JSON serializable`

Here is the object I want to serialize -

```
class MemberInfo:
    def __init__(self, member_code):
        self.memberCode = member_code
```

In Python shell -

```
>>> mi = MemberInfo('123')
>>> json.JSONEncoder().default(mi)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\Python34\lib\json\encoder.py", line 173, in default
    raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")
```

How can I find out the cause?

Comment: the json module from the Python Standard Library and Django models don't get along very well. I've grown accustomed to using jsonpickle instead: http://jsonpickle.github.io/

Comment: Can you please add your model fields? It will help determine which of them isn't serializable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the json serializer does not know how to serialize classes and that's why it stops working.

If you convert your class to a dictionary with all the properties and its values using only primitive types you can serialize it without any problems. Here is an example of how it works:

```
import json
from decimal import Decimal

class MemberInfo:
    def __init__(self, member_code):
        self.memberCode = member_code

    def to_dict(self):
        return dict(memberCode=self.memberCode)

instance = MemberInfo('123123')

try:
    # This will break since classes cannot be serialized
    json.dumps(instance)
except TypeError as e:
    print 'CLASS ERROR: %s' % e.message

# This will also break since it has a class Decimal
instance = dict(memberCode=Decimal(123123))
try:
    # This will break since classes cannot be serialized
    json.dumps(instance)
except TypeError as e:
    print 'CLASS ERROR: %s' % e.message


# This will work since there aren't any classes and all keys are simple types
instance = MemberInfo('123123').to_dict()

print 'This will return a valid result'
print json.dumps(instance)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could embed in your class a property to return data as JSON.

```
from json import dumps

class MemberInfo:

    def __init__(self, member_code, member_name):
        self.memberCode = member_code
        self.memberName = member_name

    @property
    def json(self):
        return dumps({'code': self.memberCode, 'name': self.memberName})

member = MemberInfo(1234, 'Johnny Cash')
member.json
'{"code": 1234, "name": "Johnny Cash"}'
```

Comment: I suppose that's an approach, but it doesn't answer the question well.

Comment: I really agree, but how @user3238014 presents the question, it's solution is very doable

Comment: The question is "How can I find out the cause?"

Comment: Ok, sorry. Will pay more attention next time! So much will to answer...

Answer (score 1):

The cause is simply that you haven't told it how to.

JSON is a fairly restrictive format, and can pretty much only cope with strings, integers, lists and dicts. Not even datetimes can be serialised directly. So if you want to serialise a Django model, you need to provide some form of representation in terms of the toes that json does understand.